# MSBuild V110 instead of V120

Tags: windows, msbuild

I am having some issues with installing browser-sync with npm.

The error is 
MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found.

I can confirm the path doesn't exist, however there is a V110 folder instead of V120. I presume this relates to the version of visual studio?

How do I get V120 installed / V110 removed?

Answer (score 1):

`V110`/`V120` identify a platform tool set, which is a part of `Visual Studio`. `V110` comes with `Visual Studio 2012` and `V120` comes with `Visual Studio 2013`. Either upgrade your `VS` or switch to `V110` in project properties - but whether or not it will work depends on the project (it's not necessary compatible with older build environment).

Comment: I'm uninstalling my VS10 and VS12 and reinstalling VS 2013 now will see what happens...

Comment: But there must be a way to tell msbuild to use v120 if VS 2013 is already installed.

Comment: Okay I have it, just add C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin; to your system path, restart explorer.exe and test it by opening a cmd.exe and execute msbuild, it should show v12.0 as buildversion! Works on Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 installed.